# What is 16A TLP in ESD diode and how it determines the clamping voltage of an ESD diode?

Tags: diodes, emc, esd, tvs

Please explain the meaning of 16A TLP in ESD diodes? Is the clamping voltage determined at 16A transient current flowing through diode? Please see the table in the below picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TLP is the “transmission line pulse” during an ESD   Arc.

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9007-D.PDF

I found this searching for [TVS & TLP.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=TVS%20%26%20TLP)